# REST API - How to make logins via an API stateless and secure?

Tags: api, rest, stateless

I'm struggling with an issue here. I've searched repeatedly for answers, but have been unable to find the exact answer I'm looking for. I'm attempting to build a secure authentication method for a  REST api. My question is, how do we handle a login for a REST api?

Since a REST api is meant to be stateless every time, does that mean we need to store the client's username/password on the client's end (perhaps hashed), and send it in with every request? I'd be much more comfortable using a system like authentication tokens that are created upon logging in the first time, but does that go against the basic rules of REST, since this technically creates a "state" on the server?

What is the best and most practical method to handle this? As I wrote earlier, I'm struggling to come up with an answer to this; maybe that is due to this problem not having a clear answer, but I honestly don't know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's also my understanding of REST: clients send login/password to the server along with every request. The server has to authenticate the client based on this information only. With regard to the Hypermedia principle of REST, having a user logged in is not an application state, in my understanding.